# SQL Server need the total of the previous 6 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm using SQL Server and I need to get the sum of the previous 6 rows of my table and place the results in its own column.

I'm able to get the 6th row back with the below query:

```
SELECT id
,FileSize
,LAG(FileSize,6) OVER (ORDER BY DAY(CompleteTime)) previous
FROM Jobs_analytics 
group by id, CompleteTime, Jobs_analytics.FileSize
```

which gives me the six row back, but what I need is the sum of all six rows previous.
any help would be appreciate

Mike

Comment: You have `GROUP BY`, but no aggregation functions.  Sample data and desired results would clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT ja.id, ja.FileSize, CompleteTime, 
       SUM(FileSize) OVER (ORDER CompleteTime ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as previous
FROM Jobs_analytics ja;
```

I don't see why `GROUP BY` is necessary.  There are no aggregation functions.

Note that this takes 6 days *including* the current day.  If you want the six *preceding* rows:

```
SELECT ja.id, ja.FileSize, DATE, 
       SUM(FileSize) OVER (ORDER BY CompleteTime ja.id ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as previous
FROM Jobs_analytics ja
```